# Wordpress Page Parent/Child Links

Tags: php, wordpress, web, hosting

I have a Wordpress website, and the page names are listed at the top.  On a PC, when I hover over some of my pages, it displays more child pages assigned to that certain page that I can click on.  However, if I visit my website on a touchscreen device such as an iPad or Android device, I find it impossible to click on the child pages under the parent(I have tried holding my finger on the parent page as well).  Is there any plugins that I could install to make those pages/drop down menu accessible for touchscreens? or any other solutions?
I apologize if this was hard to understand, and any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to use a mobile optimized theme.  It can be difficult to find one that looks good at full resolution and on mobile/touch devices, they might cost money, or you might  need to use your current desktop themes for other reasons.  What you can do is install WPTouch which displays a special mobile/touch optimized version of your size for those users, but leaves your full desktop site theme alone.  I believe this will require the least amount of effort and allow all of your content to be navigable.

Check out WPTouch [here](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wptouch/).

The broader question about building a responsive site or navigation system that works on mobile/touch as well as looks good at full screen width is probably goes beyond what you need, so I offer you this plugin.  Good luck!

You might also be interested in checking out the [Wordpress Stackexchange community here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).